# copy contents of a file starting from regex word to end of the file

Tags: linux, file, bash, shell, copy

I want to copy a content of a file starting from word (searched word/line) to the end of the file.

Example:
File1:

```
this is a sample text for file1 in PA
this is a sample text for file1 in CA
this is a sample text for file1 in CT
this is a sample text for file1 in IL
this is a sample text for file1 in MI
end of the file.
```

I want to copy contents to file2 from line that has "CT" till the end of the file.
Output :
File2

```
this is a sample text for file1 in CT
this is a sample text for file1 in IL
this is a sample text for file1 in MI
end of the file.
```

Comment: What if i have a scenario where i want to get content from two files and copy it to one output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/searchtext/,$p' file1 > file2
```

or `awk`:

```
awk '/searchtext/ {flag=1} flag;' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if($0~/CT/)p=1;if(p)print}' your_file
```